# URL validation in typescript

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, url, syntax

I want to make a custom validator that should check the input Url is valid or not.

I want to use the following regex that I tested in expresso, but comes off invalid when used in typescript (the compiler fails to parse it):

```
(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?((([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{2,}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})|((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]\d\d|\d?\d)(?(\.?\d)\.)){4}))(:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~]*)?
```

The above url checks for optional `http:\\\` and also will validate an Ip address
The following url's should be valid :

- 192.1.1.1
- http://abcd.xyz.in
- https://192.1.1.126
- abcd.jhjhj.lo

The following url's should be invalid:

- 192.1
- http://hjdhfjfh
- 168.18.5

Kindly assist

Comment: You should add error messages and an example how the desired result looks like.

Comment: Why did you escape the first colon?

Comment: http:// or https:// is the required format.I can't figure out how to consider '':'' in the regex

Comment: If you are really testing the cases you describe, what you are looking for is not URL validation: "http://hjdhfjfh" is a valid URL. So any answer based on using new URL(val) will fail.

Given the escapes in that regex (before the colon and dash), you probably want to wrap it in quotes and use new Regex instead of the // syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slashes `/` are not escaped in the regex.

What is valid or invalid in Javascript *is* valid or invalid in Typescript and vice-versa.

Comment: how do i escape them?

Comment: with a backslash `\`

Answer (score 1):

There may be another option for you, that relies on the `URL` class. The idea is to try converting the string into a `URL` object. If that fails, the string does not contain a valid URL.

```
public isAValidUrl(value: string): boolean {
  try {
    const url = new URL(value);
    return isValid(url.pathname);
  } catch (TypeError) {
    return false;
  }
}

isValid(value: URL): boolean {
  // you may do further tests here, e.g. by checking url.pathname
  // for certain patterns
}
```

Alternatively to returning a boolean you may return the created URL or null instead of a boolean or - if that exists in JavaScript or TypeScript: something like an `Optional<URL>`. You should adapt the method's name then, of course.

Comment: This method return as valid URL like http://.com or http://google so, It is not a valid answer.

Comment: @Ramon-san But "google" IS a valid relative URL and at the moment I am not aware of any rule that forbids paths starting with a dot - like ".com".

Comment: I thought the OP of question was looking for an absolute valid URL, not relative paths, so ```http://.com``` and ```http://google``` are not valid for absolute URLs.

Comment: I don't see, why these should not be valid URLs. However, as the OP stated some limitations I edited my code to show where additional testing might be done.